Why node app returning 404 error over ssl?
I'm running node app on vps server in subdomain, while running vue app in public_html folder. installed easyapache passenger to run node app. also installed same ssl certificate for both main and subdomain. frontend app accessible in https protocol, node app return data in http protocol, but return 404 in https protocol. seems https request is not forwarded to server for subdomain. i get test data in log in apache error log while running api in http protocol, but no log when running in https protocol. when browsing the subdomain, seems https protocol installed correctly. i also tried to setup ssl conf in this directory /etc/httpd/conf.d/nodeapp-ssl.conf with following code:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user1/api.example.com

    # Enable SSL
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/user1/ssl/certs/_wildcard__api_example_com_123.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/user1/ssl/keys/123.key       

    # Optional: Logging
    ErrorLog /home/user1/api.example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /home/user1/api.example.com/access.log combined

    # Security Headers (optional but recommended)
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"

    # Ensure the .htaccess rules are respected
    <Directory /home/user1/api.example.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user1/api.example.com

    # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

also node app error is not printing in defined location, instead logging in apache log.

No node app is involved in the configuration you show. This is just serving static content. It is unclear how your working apache configuration for plain http looks like, but there is like some ProxyPass somewhere. Your configuration for https must be similar, except for the port and added ssl settings like certificates.

I managed my api server running in easyapache passenger on https protocol by running this commands (replace username and example.com):
Copy the configuration file:
cp -a /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/username/example.com/application-name.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/username/example.com/application-name.conf

Rebuild the Apache configuration and restart Apache:
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_httpd

reference: https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/
